# How to create Accordion type side menu in ionic 4

Tags: ionic3, ionic4, accordion, side-menu

I have a project in ionic 3 with accordion menu. Now there is a necessary to update to ionic 4. 
I have converted all my codes to ionic 4 but I could not convert the menu from Ionic 3 to Ionic 4 due to lot of changes in routing methods.
Below given main part of the code of Ionic 3 Accordion side menu, how to use it in Ionic 4 ...

```
// Side Menu Component
import { SideMenuContentComponent } from './../shared/side-menu-content/side-menu-content.component';
import { SideMenuSettings } from './../shared/side-menu-content/models/side-menu-settings';
import { MenuOptionModel } from './../shared/side-menu-content/models/menu-option-model';


@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
    @ViewChild(Nav) navCtrl: Nav;

    // Get the instance to call the public methods
    @ViewChild(SideMenuContentComponent) sideMenu: SideMenuContentComponent;

    public rootPage: any = WelcomePage;

    // Options to show in the SideMenuComponent
    public options: Array<MenuOptionModel>;

    // Settings for the SideMenuComponent
    public sideMenuSettings: SideMenuSettings = {
        accordionMode: true,
        showSelectedOption: true,
        selectedOptionClass: 'active-side-menu-option',
        subOptionIndentation: {
            md: '16px',
            ios: '64px',
            wp: '56px'
        }
    };

    private unreadCountObservable: any = new ReplaySubject<number>(0);

    constructor(private platform: Platform,
                private statusBar: StatusBar,
                private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
                private alertCtrl: AlertController,
                private menuCtrl: MenuController) {
        this.initializeApp();
    }

    initializeApp() {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            this.statusBar.styleLightContent();
            this.splashScreen.hide();

            // Initialize some options
            this.initializeOptions();
        });

        // Change the value for the batch every 5 seconds
        setInterval(() => {
            this.unreadCountObservable.next(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
        }, 5000);

    }

    private initializeOptions(): void {
        this.options = new Array<MenuOptionModel>();

        // Load simple menu options
        // ------------------------------------------
        this.options.push({
            iconName: 'home',
            displayName: 'முகப்பு - Home',
            component: HomePage,

            subItems: [
                {
                    iconName: 'home',
                    displayName: 'முகப்பு-Home',
                    component: HomePage,
                },
                {
                    iconName: 'heart',
                    displayName: 'அறிமுகம்- Welcome',
                    component: WelcomePage,
                },
                {
                    iconName: 'information-circle',
                    displayName: 'எம்மைப் பற்றி- SVK',
                    component: AboutPage
                }
            ]
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This accordion has no css effects, and it is made for one level only.

### If someone knows how to add some transition effects to this accordion please tag me with it.

step 1:
Let us assume you are having total 9 pages in your ioni4 app created.

Step 2:
Save Your menu as json under assets/data/menus.json
change the url with meaningful name and url found in app.routing.module.ts

```
[
    {
        "name": "Menu1  ",
        "item": [
            {
                "icon": "calendar",
                "name": "Item1",
                "url": "/item1"
            },
            {
                "icon": "calendar",
                "name": "Item2",
                "url": "/item2"
            },
            {
                "icon": "calendar",
                "name": "Item3",
                "url": "/item3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Menu2",
        "item": [
            "item": [
            {
                "icon": "calendar",
                "name": "M2Item1",
                "url": "/m2item1"
            },
            {
                "icon": "calendar",
                "name": "M2Item2",
                "url": "/m2item2"
            },
            {
                "icon": "calendar",
                "name": "M2Item3",
                "url": "/m2item3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Menu3",
        "item": [
            "item": [
            {
                "icon": "calendar",
                "name": "M3Item1",
                "url": "/m2item1"
            },
            {
                "icon": "calendar",
                "name": "M3Item2",
                "url": "/m2item2"
            },
            {
                "icon": "calendar",
                "name": "M3Item3",
                "url": "/m2item3"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Step3: change content of your app.component.html as below:

```
<ion-content>
        <ion-list>
          <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" class="mymenu">
            <ion-item [routerDirection]="'root'" [routerLink]="['/home']" (click)="clearLevel()">
              <ion-label><ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Home, About, Contact</ion-label>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-menu-toggle>
          <ion-item *ngFor="let p of appPages; let i=index;" [routerDirection]="'root'" (click)="toggleLevel1('idx'+i)" [ngClass]="{active: isLevel1Shown('idx'+i)}">
            <ion-label>
              <ion-icon [name]="isLevel1Shown('idx'+i) ? 'md-arrow-dropdown' : 'md-arrow-dropright'" slot="end" style="font-size: 20px;"></ion-icon>
              {{p.name}}
               <ul *ngIf="isLevel1Shown('idx'+i)" class="level2">

                    <li *ngFor="let i1 of p.item; let l=index;" [routerLink]="[i1.url]">
                      <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" class="first-level"><ion-icon name="{{i1.icon}}"></ion-icon>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{i1.name}}</ion-menu-toggle>
                    </li>
                    </ul>
             </ion-label>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-menu>
    <ion-router-outlet id="main-content"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-split-pane>
</ion-app>
```

step4: add the below scss to app.component.scss file:

```
.level1 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 2px 0;

  li {
      border-top: solid 1px rgb(46, 9, 177);
 //     padding: 0px 0 0 8px;


  }

}
.level2 {
  padding-left: 5px;
  --background: rgb(218, 248, 241) !important;

  color:blue;
  line-height: 2.5;



  li {
      border-top: solid 1px orange;
     background-color: rgb(230, 248, 226);
     padding: 2px 0 0 8px;
     font-size: 14px;

  }
}

ion-split-pane{ 
  ion-content{  
    --background: rgb(218, 248, 241) !important;
  }
  ion-item{
     --background: rgb(218, 248, 241) !important;
     --color: rgb(71, 3, 148);
  }
}
```

step5: add the few lines of code in app.component.ts any where at the body of the class:

```
clearLevel() {
    this.showLevel1 = null;
    this.showLevel2 = null;
  //  this.showLevel3 = null;
  }
  toggleLevel1(idx: string) {
    if (this.isLevel1Shown(idx)) {
      this.showLevel1 = null;
    } else {
      this.showLevel1 = idx;
    }
  }
  isLevel1Shown(idx: string) {
    return this.showLevel1 === idx;
  }
```

Please let me know the result if I have missed something to mention in this.